# minimum size of the union of some nearly-disjoint sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If I have $m$ sets, each of size $n$, and any two of them share at most one element, what is the minimum possible size of their union?

If $m\leq n$ then the answer is easy enough to figure out. Think about adding one new set into the union at a time. The first one adds $n$ new elements. The second one can share at most one element with the first one, so it adds at least $n-1$ new elements. Then the third one can share at most two elements with the union of the previous two, so it adds at least $n-2$ new elements, and so on. The lower bound we get is $n+(n-1)+\cdots+(n-m+1)=mn-\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it's pretty clear that this lower bound is best possible. So that leaves us with the case in which $m>n$. We still have the lower bound $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ from the case $m=n$, but it would be very surprising if this was the best possible bound in all cases.

I don't know anything about combinatorics so I have no idea if this is a trivial result or what, but I'm hoping it has a simple elementary proof.

Comment: I think the answer would be $\frac{nm}{2}$ or $\frac{nm+1}{2}$ depending on if $nm$ is even or odd. I know the proof would be similar to the proof of this problem: Define an undirected simple graph $G$ of $m$ nodes where every node can have a maximum degree of $n$, prove that if $m>n$, there exists such a $G$, such that number of edges in graph = $\left\lfloor \frac{nm}{2} \right\rfloor$.

Comment: @EnEm See partial answers [there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288751/88984)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the link. so it seems that the general answer is unfortunately not known.

Comment: It looks so....

Comment: @EnEm I was able to turn the problem into one about a bipartite graph in which every vertex in one of the vertex sets has degree $n$, but it's not obvious to me how I would use your example to solve the problem. The issue is that it's hard to get a bound on the maximum number of sets a given element of the union can be contained in. Even if one did obtain such a bound, using your result would probably not yield a best possible bound.